# Taking value from one csv file and checking if it exists in another csv file

Tags: php, csv, preg-match

I have one csv file which looks like this

`Stanza 07,41912087207 
Stanza 08,41912087208 
Stanza 09,41912087209`

and another one which looks like this

```
0101*200,0789240959,centralino,101,2016-03-03 14:02:35,281,1.47,,4178,"La Perla" <41917913577>
0101*200,0789240959,centralino,101,2016-03-03 14:02:35,281,500.12,,4178,"La Perla" <41912087207>
0101*200,0917911974,centralino,101,2016-03-03 14:52:16,0,0,,41,"La Perla" <41917913577>
```

So I want to take ID value from the first file, check if it exists in the second csv file and if it does, print out values after the sixth comma, in lines above so it would be 500.12 since there is one ID that appears on both of CSV files 41912087207.

Here is my code

```
<?PHP
$search= "41912087207"; 
$linescdr       = file('cdr.txt');
$linesstanze = file('stanze.txt');

while (list($key, $line1) = each($linesstanze)) {

   $arrr = explode(",", $line1);

      while (list($key, $line) = each($linescdr)) {
   if(strpos($line, $arrr[1])){
   $arr = explode(",", $line);
   echo $arr[6];
   echo "<br>";
}
}

}
?>
```

In this line of code

```
if(strpos($line, $arrr[1])){
```

if i put $search which is declared in the beginning of the file, it works, but if I put $arrr[1] which would be IDs from the stanze.txt one by one in the while loop, it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: The 6th comma.. There are csv functions in PHP, use them.

Comment: I wouldn't ask here if I could solve it with the things I found.

Comment: @outbeyond His issue is that you have no error you've run into, as well as any attempt on your end to get to the solution. Please read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting.

Comment: @Arescet I have updated my post, there is my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
for id in $(cut  -f2 -d',' file1); do cat file2 | grep $id | cut -f7 -d','; done
```

And hop, you're done;